# componentWillReceiveProps is not called despite action and reducer is called

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Here is the main file which calls the respective action - addPrescription but when I am accessing this.props.prescription which should ideally contain the required data- I am unable to access componentWillReceiveProps .

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { addPrescription } from '../../actions/index';

class Prescription extends Component{
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {editorState: EditorState.createEmpty()};
this.onChange = (editorState) => this.setState({editorState});
}

createPrescription(prescription){
        this.props.addPrescription("pravandan");
        console.log(this.state.prescription);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    console.log(nextProps.prescription)
}

render(){
    return(
            <div>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <Row>
                    <Col span={12} push={6}>
                        <Button type="primary" onClick={() => this.createPrescription("")}>Submit</Button>
                        <br/>
                        <Button type="primary" onClick={() => this.createPrescription("")}>{this.props.prescription}</Button>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </div>
        );
}
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
return {
prescription : state.prescription
}
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
return {
addPrescription : prescription => dispatch(addPrescription(prescription))
}
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Prescription);
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'Unable to access `componentWillReceiveProps`? React doesn’t call componentWillReceiveProps() with initial props during mounting btw. You can read about this [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops).

Comment: @KyleRichardson yeah but I meant that this function should be get called after the action is fired, na

Comment: May I see your reducer please?

Comment: @KyleRichardson yes sure here it is - https://codepen.io/Pravandan/pen/ppEjzZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this reducer you posted:

```
const addprescription = (state=[],action) => {
        console.log("reducers received")

    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ADD_PRESCRIPTION' :
            return [
                ...state,
                {
                    prescription : action.prescription
                }
            ]

        default : 
            return state;
    }
}

export default addprescription;
```

Your reducer is named `addprescription`. In your `mapStateToProps` you will need to...

change

`prescription : state.prescription`

to

`prescription : state.addprescription`

Or better yet rename your reducer. Currently, `state.prescription` doesn't exist. `state.addprescription[0].prescription` is what would exist after your reducer takes an action, but you're still not mapping this state to your props because of the reducer name.

EDIT: After looking at your code sandbox;

I see you added `state.addprescription[0].prescription` to the `mapStateToProps`. The problem is, your initial state is an empty array, so I can see how that throws an error.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
        prescription : state.addprescription[0].prescription
    }
    console.log(state.prescription)
};
```

Change `state.addprescription[0].prescription` to `state.addprescription`.

Now you are adding objects to your `addprescription` array. So the `prescription` key you are adding to those objects in your reducer will now be available at `this.props.prescription[index].prescription`. You might want to rethink your naming convention?

Here is a bare bones [working code sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/6lxpy2lzon). Should be easily followable from the top down.

Comment: thanks.. but i am getting this error TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Would it be possible for you to make a [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) of you reducer, component, and action creator. Much easier to debug a complete module.

Comment: here it is - https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Pravandan/docspad/tree/master/

Comment: I made this [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/6lxpy2lzon). I will go look at yours now. Take a look at it, may help you before I get finished looking through yours :)

Comment: Thank you very much for this, but still I am not able to figure out the error in mine. Can you please help

Comment: Here is a [working](https://codesandbox.io/s/qvvljok6nq) version of your sandbox.

Comment: Thank you very much. What was the error and now I will be able to access the prescription value by this.props.prescription ?

Comment: You're welcome :) Read the edit I made to my answer. It explains what the error was. You were trying to access a value on an index of an empty array. I highly recommend you rethink the naming convention of your reducer and the design of your state. It does not read very intuitively.

Comment: I modified the name of my reducer to " prescriptions " and now in mapStateToProps I do => prescriptions : state.prescriptions and now when I am using this.props.prescriptions[0].prescription, it shows me the error as cannot read property '0' of undefined. Can you please look once again - https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Pravandan/docspad/tree/master/

Comment: I think there is also some other problem - you can clone the repository from here - github.com/Pravandan/docspad and check please please please. Thanks in advance

Comment: just in . it worked I had to use - prescriptions:state, Dont know why, can you guess the reason

Comment: Here you go: https://codesandbox.io/s/pw60z6l277 fixed it again. I feel like you might be missing the point though. You're not using the slice of state in your functions, how you have designed it in the reducer. Take a look at your reducer. You make an array, and put objects in it. Yet in your mapStateToProps you try to access a key of an array. The `.prescriptions` is not on the slice of state... it on the objects you push into the state array. Hope this helps.